How to hide subprocess ran from systemd service from systemd supervision?

I have a timer

# ss-agent.timer
[Unit]
Description=Timer to run agent

[Timer]
OnUnitActiveSec=60

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target


I have a service

# ss-agent.service
[Unit]
Description=Agent to run

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/srv/agent/bin/run.sh


The service may (or may not) spawn off specific "agent" processes (another binaries).
The problem

4.1. The systemd kills them (I have no estim on possible run time of an agent - up to weeks)
13:41:44 scan-01 systemd[1]: ss-agent.service: State 'stop-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
13:41:44 scan-01 systemd[1]: ss-agent.service: Killing process 105791 (job) with signal SIGKILL.
13:41:44 scan-01 systemd[1]: ss-agent.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
13:41:44 scan-01 systemd[1]: Failed to start Agent to run.

4.2. The systemd serialize the service invocations (i.e. next turn does not depend on OnUnitActiveSec, but on completion of the previous run.
What I do now
I run the "agents" using "double fork" + setsid() call (i.e. trying to "detach" them).
Sample "agent" binary (in C) traps all the signals (18 and 15 detected, reported, and sorta ignored).
The topmost code looks like
if fork():
    return # to caller
setsid()
if fork():
    exit(0) # quit intermediate child
setsid()
exec(...) # run the payload

yes, it's in python, and os.spawnl(os.P_NOWAIT, ...) doesn't help as it miss setsid() call.
So, I want the two things:

take my "agent" [sub]proceses out of systemd's supervision and leave them alone
make systemd to run my script just every 60 seconds (regardless of the time of completion of previous run)


https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204922/systemd-and-process-spawning-child-processes-are-killed-when-main-process-exits

However, this sounds like you should use a proper job scheduler,

Why Type=oneshot?

@Tom Yan, because of the timer


take my "agent" [sub]proceses out of systemd's supervision and leave them alone

Your job manager should use systemd's "start transient unit" feature to run each job in a separate, temporary .service. There is a D-Bus API for this which you could directly use via python-dbus, but for simplicity you should start with calling systemd-run via subprocess.run() (or os.spawnv).
os.spawnv(os.P_WAIT, "/usr/bin/systemd-run",
                     ["--service",
                      "--unit=job-xyz",
                      "--collect", etc, etc,
                      exe_path, *exe_args])

Neither the agent process nor job processes should not perform any 'daemonization', i.e. no double-fork() nor setsid(). Those are almost completely meaningless when used with any proper service manager, as there is no interactive shell or terminal to detach from.
(Service process tracking in systemd is based on a completely different mechanism – cgroups – which neither forking or setsid() will be able to detach from. There are supported ways to detach from a cgroup with root privileges, such as the way PAM detaches user sessions from sshd.service, but you should still prefer the systemd-run "transient service" mechanism if possible.)

make systemd to run my script just every 60 seconds (regardless of the time of completion of previous run)

Systemd only allows a single instance of a service with a given name. Instead, the script itself should be a long-running (not oneshot) service that has an internal 60-second loop.
while sleep(60):
    # I would use a thread
    if fork() == 0:
        check_for_new_jobs()
        exit()

